# how to handle "synonymns" in a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations

This is a bit of a sticky issue. I have a Rails association but need to add functionality to handle some special cases.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes
end

class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
end
```

The issue is that you could have something like this in db (identical items that might have a difference in sizing or quantity but are part of the desc and can't really be broken out due to accounting software):

```
items 
id    desc
1     a glass something
..
10    a bottle of something
..
20    a case of bottles of something


notes
id   note                           item_id
3    "a note about something"       1
```

What I want to do is create a linke so that items 1,10, and 20, when they load notes, will all load notes with an id of 1

For example:

```
item1=Item.find(1)
item1.notes[0].id  # 3

item10=Item.find(10)
item10.notes[0].id  # 3

item20=Item.find(20)
item20.notes[0].id  # 3
```

I feel like there should be a really basic way of doing this and was looking for suggestions. This is hacky but might work would be to write a dash separated list of other_ids into the notes table so that a `notes.other_ids="-10--20-"`

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes

  def sym_items
    Note.where('other_ids like ?',"%-#{self.id}-%")
  end
end
```

We really would only have to deal with this in a single scenario so a hacky sol'n woudl be ok but obviously would like better. Possibly do a has_many :through. I'm not sure about the latter - perhaps too much added complexity. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

thx

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure I fully understand the situation. It seems like you might want something like this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes
  has_many :other_item_notes
  has_many :other_notes, class_name: "Note", through: :other_item_notes, source: :note
  has_many :other_items, class_name: "Item", through: :notes, source: :other_items
end

class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  has_many :other_item_notes
  has_many :other_items, class_name: "Item", through: :other_item_notes, source: :item
end

class OtherItemNote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :note
end
```

The trick here is that you have a many-to-many association between items and notes (I assume you know how/why those other associations are supposed to work). Then we use the associations of those other items that we can now access to access their associated items. There may be complications with N+1 queries and such, but some of that can be dealt with by using `inverse_of` on your associations.

If you do it this way, you are querying against indexed `id` columns in your database searches, rather than a string comparison query like in your example above.